# private constructor in abstract class scenario

Tags: java, constructor, private, private-members

Is there is any feasible solution to have private constructor in abstract class..please advise

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private String member;

    private BaseClass(String member)
    {
        this.member = member;
    }

    ... abstract methods...
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334380/why-private-access-specifier-in-an-abstract-class-in-java-even-though-we-cannot and was answered very well there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

abstract class can have a private constructor. But that class cannot be extended by another class. Instead of adding a static inner class inside the abstract class and extends that abstract class.

```
 abstract class  Base{
public abstract void set();

private Base(){
System.out.println("Private Constructor!");
}
static class Derived extends Base{
public void set(){
System.out.println("set() method implemented!");
}
}
public static void main(String[] args){
new Base.Derived().set();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This defeats the purpose of abstract classes:

1. An abstract class must be subclassed to be used.
2. If a method is private, the subclass can't see it.

∴ It's effectively unreachable.

So, no.

---

*EDIT* @yshavit has found a hole in this logic which is very true - have a look at his comment (which should probably be an answer to the question?).

Comment: @Owl - agree wholeheartedly, but in general when people lecture or read about OOP there's a *lot* of info to convey.  Sometimes a fundamental point whizzes past and it's hard to nail down. :)

Comment: This is wrong. You can have an abstract class with a private constructor which is extended by a nested class within it. This effectively means it's an abstract class that defines (all of) its concrete subclasses. Trivial example: http://ideone.com/WyAxm

Comment: @yshavit - huh, how about that.  Well played.  Looks like you slid in 1 minute before the other answer that says the same thing...