# PHP defining private abstract function/method

Tags: php

Went over a thing like this and I don't know

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract private function test();
}
```

Is this a nonsense or NOT?

If not please explain why.

Comment: This is correct, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: No, this is _not_ nonsense. It is valid php code. Whether it does make sense is another question, that depends on what you want do achieve with it.

Comment: So what is the problem. Have you heard about abstract class and method in oops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense if you want to make that method inaccessible further down in the inheritance chain, e.g. grandchildren of that abstract class. For example:

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract private function test();
}

class FooChild extends Foo {
    private function test() 
    {
       // Here you implement the body of the method
    }

    public function bar() 
    {
        $this->test(); // This will work
        // Do something else
    }
}

class FooGrandChild extends FooChild {


}


$grandchild = new FooGrandChild();
$grandchild->test(); // This will throw an exception
```

Answer (score 1):

if you speak about private range inside you abstract class, no it is not a nonsence

> Since an abstract class can contain functionality (as opposed to an interface) it can have private variables or methods.

I will give you this link with a great answer (even it is in java, it is the same with php) [Why is there a private access modifier in an abstract class in Java, even though we cannot create an instance of an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334380/why-is-there-a-private-access-modifier-in-an-abstract-class-in-java-even-though)

Answer (score 1):

Abstract methods cannot be private, because by definition they must be implemented by a derived class. If you don't want it to be public, it needs to be protected, which means that it can be seen by derived classes, but nobody else.

The PHP manual on abstract classes shows you examples of using protected in this way.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: abstract methods can be private. I just learned that there is a confusion between the fact that an abstract function must be overridden in a children class and the visibility of it. It's more like you children have to override me but you are not allowed to see me (I'm private)

Comment: There is some difference in abstract methods in php means it is not as same as c++ or java. You can check it by searching.

Comment: This is way more correct than the accepted answer.